# What is the meaning $P[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}Z_k \le \frac{1}{2}\text{ for infinitely many }n]=0$

Tags: random, random-walk

Let $Z_1, Z_2,\ldots$ be independent identically distributed (i.i.d) binary variables with $P[Z_i = 1] = 1-\alpha $ for some $\alpha > \frac{1}{2}$.  Using the transformation $X_i=2Z_i-1$ together with the known facts on the recurrence of random walk on the integers, show that

$$P\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n Z_k \le \frac{1}{2}\text{ for infinitely many }n\right]=0$$

I'm thinking I need to use the first lemma of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma) because of the "infinitely many" term.  However, I'm unable to connect this to random walks.  Would appreciate all / any input from the community.

Comment: That should be $P\left[ \dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n Z_k \le \dfrac{1}{2} \ \text{for infinitely many } n\right] = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: In the random walk, $X_i$ is step #$i$ (to right if $+1$, left if $-1$).
Since $\alpha > 1/2$, this is a biased random walk.  What does the condition
on $\sum_{k=1}^n Z_k$ say about $\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ (which is where the random walk ends up after $n$ steps)?